# Sort objects stored in vector by string C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Imagine class with string value.

```
class Test {
public:
    string name;
};
```

Is is stored in vector

```
vector<Test> d;
```

I would like to use sort() function to sort objects in vector alphabeticaly by its name value. I know that sort() function has third parameter some kind of sorting function but i dont know how to write this function.

```
sort(d.begin(),d.end(),comp());

comp () { ? }
```

Comment: [References](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) are generally very good for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a comparator

```
bool comp(const Test &test1, const Test &test2){
    return test1.getName() <  test2.getName();
}
```

Or you can overload the `operator <` in your class

```
bool operator < (const Test &test){
    return name < test.name;
}
```

Note that if you overload the `operator <`, then you don't need to add the third parameter in the sort function.

Comment: @Paranaix, Yes, any callable object.

Answer (score 0):

`comp` will be a function that will return a `bool` to indicate the comparison in two parameters.  In your case, it should look like:

```
bool compare ( const Test& s1, const Test& s2 )
{
    return ( s1.name < s2.name );
}
```

and your call will be: `sort ( d.begin(), d.end(), compare );`

Comment: I believe it is preferable to use ``const Test& s1`` instead of simply ``Test s1`` for the parameters to avoid copying the object.